Convert subtitles so they are coded correctly (Polish and `"` even gets wrongly coded)
Wrong encoding:
1
00:01:27,879 --> 00:01:31,216
No i dupa.
Koniec z darmowym wi-fi.

2
00:01:33,009 --> 00:01:34,972
- Ki-jung!
- No?

3
00:01:35,219 --> 00:01:39,183
Kobieta z góry
zabezpieczy³a "iptime" has³em.

4
00:01:39,390 --> 00:01:41,018
Has³em?

5
00:01:41,144 --> 00:01:43,978
- Próbowa³e 123456789?
- Nie dzia³a.

6
00:01:44,103 --> 00:01:47,109
- A wspak?
- Te¿ próbowa³em!

7
00:01:47,272 --> 00:01:52,947
- Czyli koniec z WhatsAppem?
- I w ogóle wszystkim.

8
00:01:53,112 --> 00:01:54,948
Te, ojciec.

9
00:01:55,825 --> 00:01:59,662
Nie udawaj, ¿e pisz.
Co ty na to?

10
00:01:59,870 --> 00:02:06,085
Wy³¹czyli nam telefon, teraz wi-fi...

11
00:02:06,250 --> 00:02:08,211
Jaki masz plan?

12
00:02:11,924 --> 00:02:13,174
- Synu.
- Tak, tato?

13
00:02:13,258 --> 00:02:16,972
Podnie telefon wysoko,
¿eby z³apaæ sieæ.

14
00:02:18,180 --> 00:02:21,977
Poszperaj, sprawd w ka¿dym k¹cie.

15
00:02:25,855 --> 00:02:30,026
Cholerne robactwo.

16
00:02:30,485 --> 00:02:31,736
Tutaj!

17
00:02:31,860 --> 00:02:34,111
- Mam!
- Serio? Masz sygna³?

18
00:02:34,194 --> 00:02:38,701
Tak, widzisz?
Coffeeland 2G.

19
00:02:38,826 --> 00:02:40,951
Otworzy³a siê jaka nowa kawiarnia?

20
00:02:41,036 --> 00:02:44,204
- Dlaczego mój nie ³apie?
- Chod wy¿ej.

21
00:02:44,329 --> 00:02:46,251
Dzieciaki?

22
00:02:46,375 --> 00:02:48,126
- Dzia³a?
- Tak.

23
00:02:48,209 --> 00:02:50,837
To sprawd WhatsAppa.

24
00:02:50,962 --> 00:02:53,924
Mieli siê do mnie odezwaæ
z Pizza Generation.

25
00:02:54,007 --> 00:02:55,677
Czekaj.

26
00:02:55,802 --> 00:02:58,052
Jest. Pizza Generation.

27
00:03:01,431 --> 00:03:04,433
Patrzcie na to.

28
00:03:05,225 --> 00:03:08,437
Jeli bêdziemy sk³adaæ w tym tempie,
skoñczymy jeszcze dzi.

29
00:03:08,521 --> 00:03:09,731
I dostaniemy kasê.

30
00:03:09,858 --> 00:03:13,026
- Te¿ mamy wstaæ?
- Pe³na profeska.

31
00:03:13,485 --> 00:03:16,486
Co to? Dezynsekcja?

32
00:03:18,199 --> 00:03:20,703
- Nadal to robi¹?
- Jak widaæ.

33
00:03:20,828 --> 00:03:22,495
- Zamknij okno.
- Zostaw.

34
00:03:22,620 --> 00:03:25,915
Darmowe odrobaczanie.
Mo¿e zabije te pluskwiaki.

35
00:03:26,040 --> 00:03:28,582
No, ostatnio siê od nich roi

36
00:03:30,962 --> 00:03:34,340
Bo¿e, jaki smród!

37
00:03:35,718 --> 00:03:37,593
Mówi³am, ¿eby zamkn¹æ!

38
00:03:37,719 --> 00:03:40,764
Mam zamkn¹æ, tato?

39
00:03:50,688 --> 00:03:52,647
W czym problem?

40
00:03:53,399 --> 00:03:56,236
Na przyk³ad w tym.

41
00:03:56,444 --> 00:03:58,824
To ma byæ prosto?

42
00:03:58,949 --> 00:04:02,784
I dlaczego jest tu zagiête?
A to wystaje?

43
00:04:02,992 --> 00:04:05,370
Nawet nie z³o¿one.

44
00:04:06,496 --> 00:04:10,418
Jedna czwarta tak wygl¹da.

45
00:04:10,542 --> 00:04:13,586
Czyli jedno na cztery
jest do wyrzucenia.

46
00:04:16,463 --> 00:04:19,800
Naprawdê obetniesz nam 10% pensji?

47
00:04:20,387 --> 00:04:24,766
Bior¹c pod uwagê, ile z nich
jest do kitu, to chyba ma³a kara?

48
00:04:24,891 --> 00:04:27,851
I tak p³acisz nam marne grosze!
Jak mo¿esz?!

49
00:04:30,062 --> 00:04:31,398
S³uchaj.

50
00:04:31,523 --> 00:04:34,067
To nie byle co.

51
00:04:34,192 --> 00:04:39,654
Wiesz, jak jedno spartolone pude³ko
mo¿e wp³yn¹æ na wizerunek marki?

52
00:04:39,781 --> 00:04:42,699
Marki? Nie staæ was nawet,
¿eby zatrudniæ sk³adacza pude³ek.

53
00:04:42,824 --> 00:04:44,994
¯e co?!

54
00:04:45,119 --> 00:04:47,247
Szefowo.

55
00:04:47,372 --> 00:04:49,665
- To wszystko przez tamtego gocia.
- Którego?

56
00:04:49,792 --> 00:04:53,668
Tego na pó³ etatu. Gdzie prysn¹³.

57
00:04:53,795 --> 00:04:57,882
Gdy akurat macie wielkie zamówienie
od Kocio³a Mi³oci Bo¿ej.

58
00:04:58,007 --> 00:05:02,052
Sk¹d o tym wiesz?
Kto ci powiedzia³?

59
00:05:02,177 --> 00:05:03,971
Moja siostra go zna.

60
00:05:04,096 --> 00:05:08,516
Zawsze by³ trochê dziwny.
le o nim mówi¹ na miecie.

61
00:05:08,641 --> 00:05:11,103
Á propos, szefowo.

62
00:05:11,228 --> 00:05:14,399
Zgadzamy siê na obciêcie 10% pensji.
A w zamian

63
00:05:14,523 --> 00:05:15,817
W zamian?

64
00:05:15,942 --> 00:05:18,444
Mo¿e pora zatrudniæ kogo nowego?

65
00:05:18,569 --> 00:05:22,365
Potrzebujemy kogo, siostro!

66
00:05:22,490 --> 00:05:26,160
Sp³aw tamtego kolesia. Wywal go.

67
00:05:26,286 --> 00:05:29,495
Jutro przyjdê na rozmowê o pracê.
O której mam byæ?

68
00:05:29,620 --> 00:05:34,502
Zaraz, chwila.
Daj mi siê zastanowiæ.

69
00:05:34,627 --> 00:05:38,422
Dobra, to na razie
tylko zap³aæ za pude³ka.

70
00:05:44,802 --> 00:05:48,264
Zebralimy siê tu dzi

71
00:05:48,389 --> 00:05:51,853
by uczciæ zmartwychwstanie
naszych telefonów.

72
00:05:51,978 --> 00:05:55,771
I tê bezprzewodow¹ mannê z nieba!

73
00:05:55,898 --> 00:05:59,735
Patrzcie na tego.
Jeszcze nawet s³oñce nie zasz³o.

74
00:05:59,860 --> 00:06:04,365
Mówi³am, ¿eby wywiesi³
Zakaz oddawania moczu.

75
00:06:04,490 --> 00:06:09,245
Takie tabliczki tylko ich zachêcaj¹.

76
00:06:09,369 --> 00:06:12,829
- To chocia¿ na niego nakrzycz!
- Nie krzycz.

77
00:06:13,000 --> 00:06:16,168
Proszê nie sikaæ!

78
00:06:16,711 --> 00:06:19,961
Ej, to Min?

79
00:06:20,255 --> 00:06:23,716
- Proszê pana, to nie ubikacja.
- Brawo, Min.

80
00:06:23,841 --> 00:06:26,637
Ty gówniarzu!

81
00:06:26,762 --> 00:06:29,307
Na co siê gapisz, dupku?

82
00:06:29,432 --> 00:06:32,725
Chod tu, mikrusie.

83
00:06:34,562 --> 00:06:37,771
Ogarnij siê!

84
00:06:38,024 --> 00:06:40,026
Masz imponuj¹cego kolegê.

85
00:06:40,192 --> 00:06:43,278
Studenci to dopiero maj¹ wigor.

86
00:06:43,403 --> 00:06:47,783
- Nie to, co mój brat.
- On idzie do nas? Zaprosi³e go?

87
00:06:47,908 --> 00:06:49,076
Nie.

88
00:06:49,201 --> 00:06:53,038
- Czeæ!
- Czeæ, Min!

89
00:06:53,163 --> 00:06:55,581
- Jak tam u pana? Dobrze?
- Pewnie.

90
00:06:55,665 --> 00:06:58,709
- Co ty tu robisz?
- Wys³a³em ci wiadomoæ. Nie widzia³e?

91
00:06:58,834 --> 00:07:01,379
- Przepraszam, jedlicie?
- Nie, nie jedlimy.

92
00:07:01,504 --> 00:07:03,548
- Jak siê masz?
- Dobrze, a ty?

93
00:07:03,673 --> 00:07:06,552
Moglimy siê spotkaæ na miecie,
po co siê fatygowa³e?

94
00:07:06,677 --> 00:07:10,348
Przez to. Dla ciebie, bardzo ciê¿kie.

95
00:07:10,473 --> 00:07:12,848
Naprawdê? Postaw tutaj.

96
00:07:14,726 --> 00:07:16,312
Co to takiego?

97
00:07:16,437 --> 00:07:19,065
Gdy powiedzia³em, ¿e siê z tob¹ widzê,

98
00:07:19,189 --> 00:07:21,026
dziadek kaza³ przekazaæ ci to.

99
00:07:25,654 --> 00:07:29,074
To chyba kamieñ pejza¿owy.

100
00:07:29,199 --> 00:07:31,077
A mo¿e raczej abstrakcyjny?

101
00:07:31,202 --> 00:07:37,000
O, pan siê na tym zna?
Mój dziadek zbiera je od m³odoci.

102
00:07:37,125 --> 00:07:42,797
Praktycznie ca³y dom
jest nimi zawalony.

103
00:07:42,922 --> 00:07:46,634
Ten rzekomo
zapewnia rodzinie dobrobyt

104
00:07:46,757 --> 00:07:51,348
To takie metaforyczne!

105
00:07:51,473 --> 00:07:55,518
- Icie wspania³y prezent.
- Zgoda.

106
00:07:55,643 --> 00:07:59,814
Przeka¿ dziadkowi
nasze najg³êbsze podziêkowania.

107
00:07:59,939 --> 00:08:02,774
Ja bym wola³a ¿arcie.

108
00:08:11,824 --> 00:08:14,952
Jak on go nazwa³? Pejza¿owy?

109
00:08:15,079 --> 00:08:16,579
Te¿ je zbierasz?

110
00:08:16,706 --> 00:08:19,750
Ej, dziêki temu
pozna³em twoich rodziców.

111
00:08:19,875 --> 00:08:22,127
Zdrowie im chyba dopisuje.

112
00:08:23,463 --> 00:08:27,091
Zdrowie tak, gorzej z prac¹.

113
00:08:28,884 --> 00:08:32,221
Twoja siostra nadal siê uczy?

114
00:08:32,346 --> 00:08:35,557
Nie staæ jej na to.

115
00:08:44,025 --> 00:08:45,775
£adna, co?

116
00:08:46,360 --> 00:08:51,365
- To jej dajesz korki?
- Da-hye. Druga klasa liceum.

117
00:08:51,490 --> 00:08:55,036
Zostaniesz jej nowym
nauczycielem angielskiego.

118
00:08:55,161 --> 00:08:58,664
- Jak to?
- To dziana rodzina. Dobra kasa.

119
00:08:59,665 --> 00:09:00,875
I mi³a dziewczyna.

120
00:09:01,000 --> 00:09:04,043
Wyje¿d¿am na stypendium,
potrzebujê zastêpcy.

121
00:09:04,836 --> 00:09:08,258
A twoi znajomi ze studiów?

122
00:09:08,381 --> 00:09:12,095
Dlaczego prosisz o to
takiego frajera jak ja?

123
00:09:12,220 --> 00:09:14,139
A jak mylisz?

124
00:09:14,264 --> 00:09:16,474
Mdli mnie na sam¹ myl o tym,

125
00:09:16,599 --> 00:09:20,726
¿e te oblechy bêd¹ siê do niej liniæ.

126
00:09:20,851 --> 00:09:22,937
Ohyda.

127
00:09:28,653 --> 00:09:29,903
Podoba ci siê?

128
00:09:34,950 --> 00:09:37,118
Mówiê ci.

129
00:09:38,745 --> 00:09:42,790
Jak tylko pójdzie na studia,
zaproszê j¹ na randkê.

130
00:09:42,915 --> 00:09:49,047
Opiekuj siê ni¹ do tego czasu.
Do ciebie mam zaufanie.

131
00:09:50,508 --> 00:09:57,222
Dziêki, ale czy muszê udawaæ studenta?

132
00:09:58,389 --> 00:10:02,269
Stary, zastanów siê.

133
00:10:02,394 --> 00:10:04,438
Przez lata, nawet w wojsku,

134
00:10:04,563 --> 00:10:08,360
cztery razy zdawa³e egzamin na studia.

135
00:10:08,485 --> 00:10:11,986
Gramatyka, s³ownictwo,
sk³adnia, wymowa

136
00:10:12,113 --> 00:10:17,701
Jeste 10 razy lepszy
ni¿ jaki skacowany studencik.

137
00:10:19,453 --> 00:10:22,164
- Mo¿e i tak.
- No ba!

138
00:10:22,289 --> 00:10:26,001
Ale czy mnie zatrudni¹?
Nie jestem studentem.

139
00:10:26,128 --> 00:10:27,919
To ciemnij.

140
00:10:28,044 --> 00:10:32,341
Spokojnie, ja ciê polecê. Poza tym

141
00:10:32,466 --> 00:10:35,260
Jak opisaæ jej matkê

properly managed by hand with the help of neovim (though some symbols are not deciphered, they were not needed for the context):
1
00:01:27,879 --> 00:01:31,216
No i dupa.
Koniec z darmowym wi-fi.

2
00:01:33,009 --> 00:01:34,972
- Ki-jung!
- No?

3
00:01:35,219 --> 00:01:39,183
Kobieta z góry
zabezpieczyła "iptime" hasłem.

4
00:01:39,390 --> 00:01:41,018
Hasłem?

5
00:01:41,144 --> 00:01:43,978
- Próbowałeś 123456789?
- Nie działa.

6
00:01:44,103 --> 00:01:47,109
- A wspak?
- Też próbowałem!

7
00:01:47,272 --> 00:01:52,947
- Czyli koniec z WhatsAppem?
- I w ogóle wszystkim.

8
00:01:53,112 --> 00:01:54,948
Te, ojciec.

9
00:01:55,825 --> 00:01:59,662
Nie udawaj, że śpisz.
Co ty na to?

10
00:01:59,870 --> 00:02:06,085
Wyłączyli nam telefon, teraz wi-fi...

11
00:02:06,250 --> 00:02:08,211
Jaki masz plan?

12
00:02:11,924 --> 00:02:13,174
- Synu.
- Tak, tato?

13
00:02:13,258 --> 00:02:16,972
Podnieś telefon wysoko,
żeby złapać sieć.

14
00:02:18,180 --> 00:02:21,977
Poszperaj, sprawdź w każdym kącie.

15
00:02:25,855 --> 00:02:30,026
Cholerne robactwo.

16
00:02:30,485 --> 00:02:31,736
Tutaj!

17
00:02:31,860 --> 00:02:34,111
- Mam!
- Serio? Masz sygnał?

18
00:02:34,194 --> 00:02:38,701
Tak, widzisz?
Coffeeland 2G.

19
00:02:38,826 --> 00:02:40,951
Otworzyła się jakaś nowa kawiarnia?

20
00:02:41,036 --> 00:02:44,204
- Dlaczego mój nie łapie?
- Chodź wyżej.

21
00:02:44,329 --> 00:02:46,251
Dzieciaki?

22
00:02:46,375 --> 00:02:48,126
- Działa?
- Tak.

23
00:02:48,209 --> 00:02:50,837
To sprawdź WhatsAppa.

24
00:02:50,962 --> 00:02:53,924
Mieli się do mnie odezwać
z Pizza Generation.

25
00:02:54,007 --> 00:02:55,677
Czekaj.

26
00:02:55,802 --> 00:02:58,052
Jest. Pizza Generation.

27
00:03:01,431 --> 00:03:04,433
Patrzcie na to.

28
00:03:05,225 --> 00:03:08,437
Jeśli będziemy składać w tym tempie,
skończymy jeszcze dziś.

29
00:03:08,521 --> 00:03:09,731
I dostaniemy kasę.

30
00:03:09,858 --> 00:03:13,026
- Też mamy wstać?
- Pełna profeska.

31
00:03:13,485 --> 00:03:16,486
Co to? Dezynsekcja?

32
00:03:18,199 --> 00:03:20,703
- Nadal to robią?
- Jak widać.

33
00:03:20,828 --> 00:03:22,495
- Zamknij okno.
- Zostaw.

34
00:03:22,620 --> 00:03:25,915
Darmowe odrobaczanie.
Może zabije te pluskwiaki.

35
00:03:26,040 --> 00:03:28,582
No, ostatnio się od nich roi

36
00:03:30,962 --> 00:03:34,340
Boże, jaki smród!

37
00:03:35,718 --> 00:03:37,593
Mówiłam, żeby zamknąć!

38
00:03:37,719 --> 00:03:40,764
Mam zamknąć, tato?

39
00:03:50,688 --> 00:03:52,647
W czym problem?

40
00:03:53,399 --> 00:03:56,236
Na przykład w tym.

41
00:03:56,444 --> 00:03:58,824
To ma być prosto?

42
00:03:58,949 --> 00:04:02,784
I dlaczego jest tu zagięte?
A to wystaje?

43
00:04:02,992 --> 00:04:05,370
Nawet nie złożone.

44
00:04:06,496 --> 00:04:10,418
Jedna czwarta tak wygląda.

45
00:04:10,542 --> 00:04:13,586
Czyli jedno na cztery
jest do wyrzucenia.

46
00:04:16,463 --> 00:04:19,800
Naprawdę obetniesz nam 10% pensji?

47
00:04:20,387 --> 00:04:24,766
Biorąc pod uwagę, ile z nich
jest do kitu, to chyba mała kara?

48
00:04:24,891 --> 00:04:27,851
I tak płacisz nam marne grosze!
Jak możesz?!

49
00:04:30,062 --> 00:04:31,398
Słuchaj.

50
00:04:31,523 --> 00:04:34,067
To nie byle co.

51
00:04:34,192 --> 00:04:39,654
Wiesz, jak jedno spartolone pudełko
może wpłynąć na wizerunek marki?

52
00:04:39,781 --> 00:04:42,699
Marki? Nie stać was nawet,
żeby zatrudnić składacza pudełek.

53
00:04:42,824 --> 00:04:44,994
Że co?!

54
00:04:45,119 --> 00:04:47,247
Szefowo.

55
00:04:47,372 --> 00:04:49,665
- To wszystko przez tamtego gościa.
- Którego?

56
00:04:49,792 --> 00:04:53,668
Tego na pół etatu. Gdzieś prysnął.

57
00:04:53,795 --> 00:04:57,882
Gdy akurat macie wielkie zamówienie
od Kościoła Miłości Bożej.

58
00:04:58,007 --> 00:05:02,052
Skąd o tym wiesz?
Kto ci powiedział?

59
00:05:02,177 --> 00:05:03,971
Moja siostra go zna.

60
00:05:04,096 --> 00:05:08,516
Zawsze był trochę dziwny.
le o nim mówią na mieście.

61
00:05:08,641 --> 00:05:11,103
Á propos, szefowo.

62
00:05:11,228 --> 00:05:14,399
Zgadzamy się na obcięcie 10% pensji.
A w zamian

63
00:05:14,523 --> 00:05:15,817
W zamian?

64
00:05:15,942 --> 00:05:18,444
Może pora zatrudnić kogoś nowego?

65
00:05:18,569 --> 00:05:22,365
Potrzebujemy kogoś, siostro!

66
00:05:22,490 --> 00:05:26,160
Spław tamtego kolesia. Wywal go.

67
00:05:26,286 --> 00:05:29,495
Jutro przyjdę na rozmowę o pracę.
O której mam być?

68
00:05:29,620 --> 00:05:34,502
Zaraz, chwila.
Daj mi się zastanowić.

69
00:05:34,627 --> 00:05:38,422
Dobra, to na razie
tylko zapłać za pudełka.

70
00:05:44,802 --> 00:05:48,264
Zebraliśmy się tu dziś

71
00:05:48,389 --> 00:05:51,853
by uczcić zmartwychwstanie
naszych telefonów.

72
00:05:51,978 --> 00:05:55,771
I tę bezprzewodową mannę z nieba!

73
00:05:55,898 --> 00:05:59,735
Patrzcie na tego.
Jeszcze nawet słońce nie zaszło.

74
00:05:59,860 --> 00:06:04,365
Mówiłam, żebyś wywiesił
"Zakaz oddawania moczu".

75
00:06:04,490 --> 00:06:09,245
Takie tabliczki tylko ich zachęcają.

76
00:06:09,369 --> 00:06:12,829
- To chociaż na niego nakrzycz!
- Nie krzycz.

77
00:06:13,000 --> 00:06:16,168
"Proszę nie sikać!"

78
00:06:16,711 --> 00:06:19,961
Ej, to Min?

79
00:06:20,255 --> 00:06:23,716
- Proszę pana, to nie ubikacja.
- Brawo, Min.

80
00:06:23,841 --> 00:06:26,637
Ty gówniarzu!

81
00:06:26,762 --> 00:06:29,307
Na co się gapisz, dupku?

82
00:06:29,432 --> 00:06:32,725
Chodź tu, mikrusie.

83
00:06:34,562 --> 00:06:37,771
Ogarnij się!

84
00:06:38,024 --> 00:06:40,026
Masz imponującego kolegę.

85
00:06:40,192 --> 00:06:43,278
Studenci to dopiero mają wigor.

86
00:06:43,403 --> 00:06:47,783
- Nie to, co mój brat.
- On idzie do nas? Zaprosiłeś go?

87
00:06:47,908 --> 00:06:49,076
Nie.

88
00:06:49,201 --> 00:06:53,038
- Cześć!
- Cześć, Min!

89
00:06:53,163 --> 00:06:55,581
- Jak tam u pana? Dobrze?
- Pewnie.

90
00:06:55,665 --> 00:06:58,709
- Co ty tu robisz?
- Wysłałem ci wiadomość. Nie widziałeś?

91
00:06:58,834 --> 00:07:01,379
- Przepraszam, jedliście?
- Nie, nie jedliśmy.

92
00:07:01,504 --> 00:07:03,548
- Jak się masz?
- Dobrze, a ty?

93
00:07:03,673 --> 00:07:06,552
Mogliśmy się spotkać na mieście,
po co się fatygowałeś?

94
00:07:06,677 --> 00:07:10,348
Przez to. Dla ciebie, bardzo ciężkie.

95
00:07:10,473 --> 00:07:12,848
Naprawdę? Postaw tutaj.

96
00:07:14,726 --> 00:07:16,312
Co to takiego?

97
00:07:16,437 --> 00:07:19,065
Gdy powiedziałem, że się z tobą widzę,

98
00:07:19,189 --> 00:07:21,026
dziadek kazał przekazać ci to.

99
00:07:25,654 --> 00:07:29,074
To chyba kamień pejzażowy.

100
00:07:29,199 --> 00:07:31,077
A może raczej abstrakcyjny?

101
00:07:31,202 --> 00:07:37,000
O, pan się na tym zna?
Mój dziadek zbiera je od młodości.

102
00:07:37,125 --> 00:07:42,797
Praktycznie cały dom
jest nimi zawalony.

103
00:07:42,922 --> 00:07:46,634
Ten rzekomo
zapewnia rodzinie dobrobyt

104
00:07:46,757 --> 00:07:51,348
To takie metaforyczne!

105
00:07:51,473 --> 00:07:55,518
- Iście wspaniały prezent.
- Zgoda.

106
00:07:55,643 --> 00:07:59,814
Przekaż dziadkowi
nasze najgłębsze podziękowania.

107
00:07:59,939 --> 00:08:02,774
Ja bym wolała żarcie.

108
00:08:11,824 --> 00:08:14,952
Jak on go nazwał? Pejzażowy?

109
00:08:15,079 --> 00:08:16,579
Też je zbierasz?

110
00:08:16,706 --> 00:08:19,750
Ej, dzięki temu
poznałem twoich rodziców.

111
00:08:19,875 --> 00:08:22,127
Zdrowie im chyba dopisuje.

112
00:08:23,463 --> 00:08:27,091
Zdrowie tak, gorzej z pracą.

113
00:08:28,884 --> 00:08:32,221
Twoja siostra nadal się uczy?

114
00:08:32,346 --> 00:08:35,557
Nie stać jej na to.

115
00:08:44,025 --> 00:08:45,775
Ładna, co?

116
00:08:46,360 --> 00:08:51,365
- To jej dajesz korki?
- Da-hye. Druga klasa liceum.

117
00:08:51,490 --> 00:08:55,036
Zostaniesz jej nowym
nauczycielem angielskiego.

118
00:08:55,161 --> 00:08:58,664
- Jak to?
- To dziana rodzina. Dobra kasa.

119
00:08:59,665 --> 00:09:00,875
I miła dziewczyna.

120
00:09:01,000 --> 00:09:04,043
Wyjeżdżam na stypendium,
potrzebuję zastępcy.

121
00:09:04,836 --> 00:09:08,258
A twoi znajomi ze studiów?

122
00:09:08,381 --> 00:09:12,095
Dlaczego prosisz o to
takiego frajera jak ja?

123
00:09:12,220 --> 00:09:14,139
A jak myślisz?

124
00:09:14,264 --> 00:09:16,474
Mdli mnie na samą myśl o tym,

125
00:09:16,599 --> 00:09:20,726
że te oblechy będą się do niej ślinić.

126
00:09:20,851 --> 00:09:22,937
Ohyda.

127
00:09:28,653 --> 00:09:29,903
Podoba ci się?

128
00:09:34,950 --> 00:09:37,118
Mówię ci.

129
00:09:38,745 --> 00:09:42,790
Jak tylko pójdzie na studia,
zaproszę ją na randkę.

130
00:09:42,915 --> 00:09:49,047
Opiekuj się nią do tego czasu.
Do ciebie mam zaufanie.

131
00:09:50,508 --> 00:09:57,222
Dzięki, ale czy muszę udawać studenta?

132
00:09:58,389 --> 00:10:02,269
Stary, zastanów się.

133
00:10:02,394 --> 00:10:04,438
Przez lata, nawet w wojsku,

134
00:10:04,563 --> 00:10:08,360
cztery razy zdawałeś egzamin na studia.

135
00:10:08,485 --> 00:10:11,986
Gramatyka, słownictwo,
składnia, wymowa

136
00:10:12,113 --> 00:10:17,701
Jesteś 10 razy lepszy
niż jakiś skacowany studencik.

137
00:10:19,453 --> 00:10:22,164
- Może i tak.
- No ba!

138
00:10:22,289 --> 00:10:26,001
Ale czy mnie zatrudnią?
Nie jestem studentem.

139
00:10:26,128 --> 00:10:27,919
To ściemnij.

140
00:10:28,044 --> 00:10:32,341
Spokojnie, ja cię polecę. Poza tym

141
00:10:32,466 --> 00:10:35,260
Jak opisać jej matkę

...
How do I actually do it the proper way
$ file parasite_subs.srt 
parasite_subs.srt: SubRip, Non-ISO extended-ASCII text, with CRLF, NEL line terminators

I've tried https://subtitletools.com/convert-text-files-to-utf8-online but this doesn't seem to work. I need a proper solution

The file one can download from https://privatebin.net/?33d6d03020db9b8a#3UpovnE1T8TMUnSxy48epDiKbenkbz9GnTNHXiNv2NWC appears to be UTF-8 encoded, but converted from the wrong single-byte encoding, I can get it to something that looks right with:
iconv -f utf-8 -t latin1 < paste-33d6d03020db9b8a.txt |
  iconv -f windows-1250 -t utf-8

On some of the problematic lines in the sample you've now added to your question:
<<'EOF'iconv -f utf-8 -t latin1 | iconv -f windows-1250 -t utf-8
Kobieta z góry
zabezpieczy³a "iptime" has³em.
Has³em?
- Próbowa³e 123456789?
- Nie dzia³a.
- Te¿ próbowa³em!
Wy³¹czyli nam telefon, teraz wi-fi.
EOF

Gives:
Kobieta z góry
zabezpieczyła "iptime" hasłem.
Hasłem?
- Próbowałe 123456789?
- Nie działa.
- Też próbowałem!
Wyłączyli nam telefon, teraz wi-fi.

That is it was probably in the Microsoft windows-1250 to start with but was converted to utf-8 assuming it was latin1 (aka iso-8859-1) instead.
file's output would suggest your actual file is not the one that one can download from that privatebin.net web site. It's possibly still encoded in windows-1250, so you'd just need
<parasite_subs.srt iconv -f windows-1250 -t utf-8

